# How to simulate entries in HOSTS file with an IE 7 browser plugin

Tags: browser, browser-addons, internet-explorer, hosts

Is it possible in Internet Explorer 7 to simulate HOSTS file entries with a plugin?

For example, can you tell IE to resolve all requests for xyz.com to a specific IP address?

We have some QA testers which are testing a specific URL. They cannot get administrative access to change their HOSTS file.

Is it possible in Firefox or any other browsers?

Comment: Wouldn't you need admin priveledges to install an IE add-on anyway?  I'm not sure if Ad-Blocker Plus can do what you want (I think Firefox does not need admin access for add-ons), but I am not sure as I do not use it.

Comment: If IE requires admin privs to install add-ons, then my question is invalid...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser with its own hosts file?](http://superuser.com/questions/221706/browser-with-its-own-hosts-file)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same thing, but you could use a proxy server that redirects requests appropriately. Polipo and Squid can do that, among others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fool your system about dns results you need to have administrative rights in some way or another (edit hosts file, install a proxy, change network settings to use a proxy, and so on...).

Answer (score 0):

For Internet Explorer, I did not find any addon as of 2015/05/30.

For other browser, you can use HostsAdmin.

Install [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hostadmin-app/mfoaclfeiefiehgaojbmncmefhdnikeg?hl=en-US) or [Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/hostadmin/)

Then you need to grant your computer's account write permissions to file hosts like following:

Windows Vista/7 
open cmd as Administrator and type following command:
To Users group

```
cacls %windir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts /E /G Users:W
```

Custom User account

```
cacls %windir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts /E /G "User Account Name":W
```

Linux (Ubuntu Fedora ...) 
open terminal and type following command:

```
sudo chmod og+w /etc/hosts
```

Mac OS X
open terminal and type following command:

```
sudo chmod og+w /etc/hosts
```