# How to force any program to use SOCKS?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, proxy

I want to use a SOCKS proxy for all my programs that want to connect to Internet. I am connected to my ISP using an ADSL modem.

Is there any virtual system or settings which can let me do this?

I don't want to buy or use VPN.

Comment: Proxifier should be able to do the trick. – https://www.proxifier.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a chance, let me know how it goes

I have heard of these programs mentioned, but haven't tried them

"If the Internet program you are using does not have a socks proxy option you can use Sockscap to make it support socks proxy. Here is a tutorial showing how to use Sockscap."
http://www.socksproxychecker.com/sockscap.html

and you may be interested in trying this one
"Sockschain is a program that allows to work with any Internet service through a chain of SOCKS or HTTP proxies.."
http://ufasoft.com/socks/

Comment: The equivalent program on Linux is `tsocks` - or `torsocks` if you're sockisfying to Tor.

Comment: Is there a command line version of something like sockscap?

Comment: Also, sockscap doesn't seem to work in 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @ultrasawblade this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325789/tsocks-alternative-for-windows   mentions  tsocks  but can it work transparently?

Comment: @TimLudwinski the stackoverflow link in my comment to ultrasawplade  mentions 'widecap' http://widecap.ru/en/download/      I haven't tried it. It looks like the program may be free, but they charge about $10 a month min for the proxies. If you have a proxy already then maybe it's free It is freeware, and a spinoff of freecap http://www.freecap.ru  do report back if you find they work/don't work. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you probably already have a Proxy Server in mind that you'd like to use, you can configure this for all applications in your OS through the Control Panel...

1. Open "Control Panel"
2. Double-click on the "Internet options" icon
3. Activate the "Connections" tab
4. Click on the "LAN settings" button below the "Local Area Network (LAN) settings" heading
5. Enter your Proxy Server's address below the "Proxy server settings" heading

[image]

[image]

Comment: Right , but what you just told is for only IE . but i want all my proggies to use SOCKS e.g Autodesk 3DSMax or whatever program should always use the SOCKS.

Comment: Well, as I understand it most applications will use these settings as they are supposed to be OS-wide.  Internet Explorer just defaults to whatever is specified for the OS (which is what these settings are for).  Does this not work if you specify your Proxy Server here?

Comment: Not for me , check this with your `http://sockslist.net` . Everything will start to work if you type some web addresses in IE but not with FF or other applications.

Comment: Did you use the "Advanced" button to configure it specifically?  After that, if you still have applications that won't use the Proxy Server settings you configured for them, you can always set up Squid (a popular free and open source Proxy Server) on another computer, which can be configured to use a Proxy Server of your choosing, and then use your Squid computer as your gateway.

Comment: yes i had used the advanced tab.

Comment: If you can't find a "Proxy configuration" option in your applications (in this case, Autodesk 3DSMax), then it's probably bypassing the MS-Windows Proxy Server settings and you may need to go with the "Squid" option I suggested (or something similar).