# Browser and alternate host file

Tags: browser, dns, resolution, hostname

I'm testing some software using a browser. I want to start a Chromium of FireFox session, and instruct the browser to an alternate `host` file. The host file will redirect a couple of domains to the local machine for testing. If the domain is *not* present in the alternate host file, then name resolution should proceed as normal.

I don't want to modify the real `/etc/host` or my DNS server because I only need the changes for local testing with a particular browser instance.

Is it possible to instruct Chromium of FireFox (or another browser) to use an alternate `host` file for testing? Or is there another solution that I missed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser with its own hosts file?](http://superuser.com/questions/221706/browser-with-its-own-hosts-file) also see: http://superuser.com/questions/193818/how-to-simulate-entries-in-hosts-file-with-an-ie-7-browser-plugin?rq=1

Comment: techie007 - yes, nice find. I added a close vote (or should I delete the question?).

Comment: Doesn't hurt to leave it as "closed" (vs deleting it), as it can help others find the answer via searching. :)